# no puedo traer los datos desde mi reducer hacia mi componente hecho con redux sagas

Tags: reactjs, redux

como he comentado en el titulo , estoy intentando traerme los datos de una api a mi componente, desde el componente puedo enviar mi petición sin problema , pasa por el reducer , comienza la action , la pasa al sagas , hace la llamada dentro del sagas y la respuesta vuelve a llegar al reducer con otra accion que es success , pero sin embargo , cuando tiene que volverse a renderizar el componente con la nueva respuesta , no se renderiza, supongo que será algo que no he hecho bien en los ciclos de vida o no se ha conectado el mapstatetoprops con el reducer bien, pongo el codigo:

```
mi componente Cocteleria.jsx

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchCoctelNameStart } from "../Store/actions/actions";


class Cocteleria extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nameCoctel: "", // Aquí almacenaremos el valor del input
    };
  }
  

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ nameCoctel: event.target.value });
    console.log("obtenemos input", this.state.nameCoctel);
  };

  handleFetchCoctel = () => {
    const { nameCoctel } = this.state;
    // Llama a tu acción pasando el valor del input
    this.props.fetchCoctelNameStartAction(nameCoctel);
    console.log("enviamos nombre", nameCoctel);
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.nameCoctel !== this.props.nameCoctel) {
      console.log("Datos actualizados:", this.props.nameCoctel);
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log("en el componente", this.props.nameCoctel, this.state.name);
    const { loading, nameCoctel, error } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          className="inputCoctel"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Introduce el nombre del cóctel"
          value={this.state.nameCoctel}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <button className='boton' onClick={this.handleFetchCoctel}>Fetch Coctel Name</button>
        <div>
        <p>nameCoctel: {nameCoctel}</p>
        <p>error: {error ? error.message : 'Ningún error'}</p>
          <div key={this.props.nameCoctel?.name}>
            <h1>{this.props.nameCoctel?.name}</h1>
            <h1>Ingredients:{nameCoctel} </h1>
            <ul>
              {/* Aquí puedes mapear los ingredientes si existen */}
              {this.props.nameCoctel?.ingredients?.map((ingredient, index) => (
                <li key={index}>{ingredient}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>


          <p>No data available.</p>

        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loading: state.loading,
    nameCoctel: state.nameCoctel,
    error: state.error,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchCoctelNameStartAction: (nameCoctel) =>
    dispatch(fetchCoctelNameStart(nameCoctel)),
});

//si quisiera añadir un console.log para ver si se despacha la accion
/**/

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cocteleria);




//falta por llevarme desde mapstatetoprops el nombre que recibo de la api a mi componente





mis actions.js

export const fetchCoctelNameStart = (nameCoctel) => ({
  type: 'FETCH_COCTEL_NAME_START',
  payload: { nameCoctel, loading: true },
});

export const fetchCoctelNameSuccess = (data) => ({
  type: 'FETCH_COCTEL_NAME_SUCCESS',
  payload: { data, loading: false },
});

export const fetchCoctelNameFailed = (error) => ({
  type: 'FETCH_COCTEL_NAME_FAILED',
  payload: { error, loading: false },
});


mi reducer.js

import '../actions/actions';

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  nameCoctel: '',
  error: null,
};

const coctelReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_COCTEL_NAME_START': {
      console.log("estoy en el reducer");
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        nameCoctel: action.payload.nameCoctel,
      };
    }
    case 'FETCH_COCTEL_NAME_SUCCESS': {
      console.log("activo success del reducer",action.payload.data);
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        nameCoctel: action.payload.data,
      };
    }
    case 'FETCH_COCTEL_NAME_FAILED': {
      console.log("activo failed del reducer");
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        nameCoctel: action.payload.error,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default coctelReducer;


mi sagas

import { call, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { fetchCoctelNameSuccess, fetchCoctelNameFailed, fetchCoctelNameStart } from '../actions/actions';

function* fetchCoctelNameGenerator(action) {
  try {
    const { nameCoctel } = action.payload;
    const url = `https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/cocktail?name=${nameCoctel}`;
    const headers = {
      method: 'GET',
      'X-Api-Key': '+m6oiBjVoWBGJcUs96gIMA==SgGhz4SrKAqSM1Fu',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    const response = yield fetch(url, { headers });
    const data = yield response.json(); // Espera a que la promesa se resuelva
    console.log("datos en el sagas",data);
    console.log("en el sagas 2",data[0]);
    console.log("en el sagas 3",data[0].name);
    yield put(fetchCoctelNameSuccess(data[0]));
  } catch (response) {
    yield put(fetchCoctelNameFailed(response));
  }
}

function* mySaga() {
  yield takeEvery('FETCH_COCTEL_NAME_START', fetchCoctelNameGenerator);
}

export default mySaga;
import { call, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { fetchCoctelNameSuccess, fetchCoctelNameFailed, fetchCoctelNameStart } from '../actions/actions';

function* fetchCoctelNameGenerator(action) {
  try {
    const { nameCoctel } = action.payload;
    const url = `https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/cocktail?name=${nameCoctel}`;
    const headers = {
      method: 'GET',
      'X-Api-Key': '+m6oiBjVoWBGJcUs96gIMA==SgGhz4SrKAqSM1Fu',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    const response = yield fetch(url, { headers });
    const data = yield response.json(); // Espera a que la promesa se resuelva
    console.log("datos en el sagas",data);
    console.log("en el sagas 2",data[0]);
    console.log("en el sagas 3",data[0].name);
    yield put(fetchCoctelNameSuccess(data[0]));
  } catch (response) {
    yield put(fetchCoctelNameFailed(response));
  }
}

function* mySaga() {
  yield takeEvery('FETCH_COCTEL_NAME_START', fetchCoctelNameGenerator);
}

export default mySaga;





DATOS QUE VEO EN EL INSPECTOR CUANDO ENVIO EL DATO (DEBE HACERSE SIN CORS EN EL NAVEGADOR , EN LINUX hacer esto en la terminal google-chrome --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_session" --disable-web-security)


llamada:
https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/cocktail?name=whisky
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
200
respuesta:
[
    {
        "ingredients": [
            "1 1/2 oz Japanese Whisky (such as suntory toki)",
            "3/4 oz Bianco Vermouth, Dolin",
            "1/2 oz Amaro Montenegro",
            "1 ds Bitters, Angostura orange",
            "1 twst Lemon peel (garnish)"
        ],
        "instructions": "Stir, up, coupe or Nick and Nora, garnish lemon peel.",
        "name": "yamabuki whisky cocktail"
    },
    {
        "ingredients": [
            "2 oz Islay Scotch",
            "3/4 oz Oloroso sherry",
            "1 bsp Maple syrup",
            "6 ds Cherry Bitters (or use 1 bsp of Cherry Heering)"
        ],
        "instructions": "Stir, strain to lowball with big ice. Garnish with lemon zest.",
        "name": "whisky in church"
    },
    {
        "ingredients": [
            "1 1/2 oz Ginger Wine",
            "1 1/2 oz Blended Scotch"
        ],
        "instructions": "Stir together without ice.",
        "name": "whisky mac"
    }
]
```

Comment: Debes [edit] tu pregunta para agregar más detalles. La zona de comentarios es para aclaraciones: como verás, tu código es ilegible aquí.

Comment: llevas razón , dejo la actualización del codigo en este enlace,
(ahora se consigue que se pinte el nombre del coctel al escribirlo y darle al boton , pero!, salta un error , por lo que he visto es , por como se llama a las propiedades del objeto de respuesta pero no se como solucionarlo, debe hacerse sin hooks y con componentes de clase gracias)
https://github.com/Alejandrobermejo16/RepositorioAprendizaje/tree/master/ProyectoCocteleria/cocteleria/src

Comment: Ya he dado con una solución provisional que no se si es del todo correcta o se puede hacer mejor desde el sagas quizás
la he subido a github , pero basicamente la solucion es cambiar la forma en que representas el objeto:
incorrecta ->  <p>{nameCoctel.instructions}</p>
correcta -> <h1>{JSON.stringify(nameCoctel.name)}</h1>

si alguien encuentra una solucion mas legible por favor ponerlo por aquí gracias a todos.
tambien dejo la pagina donde lo he visto https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-objects-are-not-valid-as-react-child

Comment: El código siempre debe estar presente en la pregunta (o en la respuesta, si es una respuesta). Los enlaces pueden caer. Recuerda además que el formato del sitio, justamente, es de _preguntas y respuestas_.

Answer (score 0):

fijate que que tienes un input para meter el nombre del coctel y fijate en lo que estás mandando al endpoint:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estás seguro que eso es lo que quiere recibir el endpoint de la api? en cada espacio setea un "%20" y no pinta nada porque no te está devolviendo nada el endpoint

Answer (score 0):

gracias por la respuesta, voy a subirlo por capturas ya que no me deja o no conozco como copiar el codigo sin pasar el limite de caracteres. esa llamada que me indicas , ami no me da respuesta solamente si tengo el navegador por cors , y lo que si es cierto es que al poner el espacio aparece en la llamada 20% pero me devuelve aun asi los ingredientes que es el fin de la app , el formato que devuelve debo adecuarlo , pero en este caso , lo importante es que me devolviera algo , aún así, no controlo aún el tema , y estaré encantado de ver mejores soluciones , gracias (: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la izq es el navegador con coors y la derecha sin coors

para desactivar coors -> abrir terminal en mi caso en ubutnu , abrir terminal y poner google-chrome --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_session" --disable-web-security